# No Django POST data when sent over a form?

Tags: python, django, forms, http, post

I am on a development server (no CSRF protection), sending over login data to Django via a web form (Django: 127.0.0.1:8000).
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Log In</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<header>

</header>
<script> 
$("document").ready(function () {
$("header").load("static/header.html");
})
</script>
<div id="loginbox">
<h3>Log In</h3>
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000" method="post">
<input type="text" id="uname"><br>
<input type="password" id="pass"><br>
<button id="login" type="submit">Log In</button></br>
</form>
<a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a><br>
<a href="forgotCredentials.html">Forgot Username/Password?</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Django:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.


from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse

@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    uname = request.POST.get("uname")
    passwd = request.POST.get("pass")
    print(uname + " pass " + passwd)
    user = authenticate(username=uname, password=passwd)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return render(request, "taxnow/index.html")
    return render(request, "taxnow/Login.html")
```

I'm pretty sure that the POST data is not being transmitted (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str') in the print statement, but I can't figure out why.
(The HTML is on localhost and the django is on 127.0.0.1:8000 as mentioned previously.) Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `request.POST` you don't have keys from `id` attribute, but from `name`. Add it to inputs and you're fine.

```
<input type="text" id="uname" name="uname"><br>
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass"><br>
```